# Boost: mutex unlocking from any thread possible?

Tags: multithreading, boost, mutex

I started using boost::thread recently (WinXP, VS10, BoostPro) and found that mutex can be unlocked by any thread, not by the thread that owns it only.
Additionally it seams that the basic lock_guard + mutex combo is doing some internal counting of multiple lock() and unlock() but it is not a big issue I guess.

Does somebody know why it was designed in such a way? Is it on purpose?
(or maybe there is something wrong with my build environment / libs?)

Example app:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace std;


class NamedThread
{
public:
    NamedThread(string name_, boost::mutex& mtx_) :
      mtx(mtx_), name(name_) {}

    void operator ()()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
            cout << name << endl;

            //boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard1(mtx);
            //boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard2(mtx);

            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> guard1(mtx);
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> guard2(mtx);
        }


    }

    string name;
    boost::mutex& mtx;
};

class UnlockerThread
{
public:
    UnlockerThread(string name_, boost::mutex& mtx_) :
      mtx(mtx_), name(name_) {}

    void operator ()()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(3000));
            cout << name << ": unlocking" << endl;
            mtx.unlock(); // !!! IT WORKS !!!
        }
    }

    string name;
    boost::mutex& mtx;
};


int main()
{
    boost::mutex mtx;

    NamedThread th2("Thread1", mtx);
    boost::thread t2(th2);

    UnlockerThread th3("UnlockerThread", mtx);
    boost::thread t3(th3);

    t2.join();

    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The boost documentation is very clear that a precondition for calling mutex.unlock is that "the current thread owns *this." That doesn't mean that violating that precondition will result in an exception/error/crash (although it might be nice for a debug build), but you can't rely on any specific behaviour in that case.

The win32 implementation appears to implement most of the logic for a mutex using atomic instructions - presumably this is because of limited support for more complex mutex types (recursive/timed) on win32. Win32's native critical sections can only be used for simple mutexes (and Win32's native mutexes are too heavyweight for in-process mutexes).

Comment: So I guess my dev environment is OK. I'm perfectly aware what is in the boost documentation but I believe this kind of behavior can lead to a very serious and hard to detect errors in large applications. Documentation statement alone cannot prevent programming errors. In my opinion there should be at least some assertion in debug builds as you pointed out as well as an information in docs about undefined behavior in such a case. Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: @Oedo808 In addition to your comment on Win32's implementation. I believe in 1_55 boost is using Lamport's bakery (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport's_bakery_algorithm).